# Ipv6 Source Address selection in linux

Tags: c, linux, ipv6

To get destination derive from an host name or to apply destination address selection algorithm (as per RFC 3484) we have an library api `getaddrinfo()`. If you search on net you would find that the same API could be used for Source address selection. But when i tested it practically it's not happening.

When i did some homework on it found that in linux the kernel itself decides the appropriate source address depending upon the destination address by applying those rules (as per RFC 3484). This is done by kernel in `fib6_rule_action()` method this is done while sending the data (e.g. in `sendto()`).

My question is there any library API or system call which could do this for me at earlier stage meaning before sending data.

Comment: To make sure I have this straight: You want to send a UDP packet to someone, and specify the source address?

Comment: It's unclear what you really want, but if you connect() the socket, you'll get the source address with getsockname(). (If in the future the kernel routing table changes, the source address might change too though - atleast for UDP).

Comment: yes that is what i want but since i have multiple ipv6 address how would i make the decision from which source ip should i send the data. is there any library API which would actually give me the sorted source IP list according to the destination ip address.

Answer (score 1):

You can get that information via [linux routing sockets aka rtnetlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html). Specifically it is the RTA_SRC you are looking for.

A word of warning, (rt)netlink sockets are not the easiest protocol to use and there is not much up to date documentation besides the source code. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) for netlink might get you started. Some of the External Links seem good and the linked paper contains more references.

I suggest using a library, if you can find one and your netlink related code is any longer than the single source address query. [Libnl](http://www.carisma.slowglass.com/~tgr/libnl/) or [libmnl](http://netfilter.org/projects/libmnl/index.html) might be good. The former also has a nice page about [routing sockets](http://www.carisma.slowglass.com/~tgr/libnl/doc/route.html).

**As a test**, you can get the same functionality with the user space command `ip -6 route get <dst_addr>` eg `ip -6 route get 2a00:1450:4010:c04::63`.

Comment: I was not that clear while mentioning the question i guess. If you see my comment on jonathon-reinhart reply than you would get what i want. To clarify a bit more I want that from the multiple IPv6 address IP (I have) system should give me the most prefer address depending upon the destination address where i want to send the data. Is there any mechanism for this. And by most prefer address I meant by applying those rules defined in RFC3484. (Again what i want is source address and not the destination address because for destination we have getaddrinfo)

Comment: My answer points out a way to do exactly what you ask. Though it is not an API as such, but a protocol.

Comment: @thouvila ip is an utility but i think that it  goes upto the route level. I got to know from this link (http://linux-hacks.blogspot.in/2008/07/default-address-selection-part-2.html) that source address selection comes into picture after route algorithms. Is this true or am I going in the wrong direction ????

Comment: ip is only an utility, yes. I put the command in the answer to help you get a picture of what kind of information the rtnetlink socket returns. I do not in any way recommend calling ip directly from your program. Use the netlink sockets to obtain the same information. A message to rtnetlink will return the source address that would be selected in the linux FIB, i.e. the same logic that your link describes.

Comment: I tried it by using rtnetlink. Now i have reached the stage where i can see the whole routing table. But still when i give an destination address as an attribute to netlink message i get stucked up. Can you help me with this. Also it would be fine if we can get how ip route get works internally then it can be resolved.

Comment: You can get the `ip` sources by doing a  `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git` The projects homepage is at http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2

Comment: @thuovilla Thanks for you help. Finally made it done. Thanks for all the help